# Rails using Devise LDAP authenticable gem to get all LDAP users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I've been using Devise's LDAP_authenticable gem for weeks now with a Rails 4 application and it works great for authenticating and finding a users LDAP information when I have someone's samaccountname.

Is there no way to use this gem to simply view all users in a LDAP Active Directory?

This seems pretty common, I was hoping that someone has already discovered how to do this?